# Handle ampersand in a URL in Flask

Tags: python, flask, url-routing, jinja2

I am new to web-development using Flask and Jinja2 templates.
One column in a row of my HTML table in the template is:

```
<td><a> href="/plot?label={{stats[0]}}">{{stats[0]}} </a></td>
```

`stats[0]` is a variable which is a string and might contain an '&' e.g. "Eggs & Spam".
Now in the view (views.py):

```
@app.route("/plot", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def on_plot():
    data = request.args
    label_name = data['label']
```

In this case I get `data` as `ImmutableMultiDict([(' Spam', u''), ('label', u'Eggs ')])`
which is not correct. Instead I want `ImmutableMultiDict([('label', u'Eggs & Spam ')])`

So how do I handle this case ? I tried doing `{{stats[0]|escape}}` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to build the URL from the view instead, using [`url_for`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.url_for):

```
<td><a> href="{{ url_for('on_plot', label=stats[0]) }}">{{stats[0]}} </a></td>
```

The `url_for()` method will build a query string for you and escape the ampersand appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment as it did not apply. Even though I happened to use Flask, neither JS nor HTML is generated (only the web service is), so I found what I needed in the following question, which has nothing to do with Flask and everything with URL encoding in JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript